# Tackling multiscale problem in numerical simulation

Tags: computational-physics, numerics, simulation, molecular-dynamics, particle-in-cell

In a dusty plasma system there are more than one component with different masses, i.e, electrons, ions,neutrals and dust grains. Accordingly, there are more than one temporal and spatial scales involved. I am aware that such a system is difficult to simulate, because, due to very different scales involved it may require a very large no. sample to be collected and this may not be feasible  with the available computational resources. But, such multicomponent simulations are done, for example, using Particle In Cell method. How this problem of multiple scales is overcome in PIC simulation ?